# Add hypen to file if there in a blank space in a certain position

Tags: java, file, io

If the substring position (6,7) is a blank space, I want that blank space to be replaced with a hyphen (used while loop because there are many in this file). I tried the below, trying to use concatenation to link together the new line but the blank space still exists.

Right Now:
ABCDEF YZ

What I need:
ABCDEF-YZ

Here is a block of code:

```
String line= inputFile.readLine();

   while(line!= null)
   {
       if (line.charAt(6) == ' ')           {
           String outputWithHyphen = line.substring(0,6) + '-' + 
           line.substring(7);
           outputFile.println(outputWithHyphen);
       }
       outputFile.println(line); 
       line= inputFile.readLine();
    }
```

Removed if clause, now works, really want the if clause though.

```
           String outputWithHyphen = lineOfText.substring(0,6) + '-' + 
           lineOfText.substring(7);

           outputFile.println(outputWithHyphen);
           lineOfText = inputFile.readLine();
```

Thank you for all of your support!

TL;DR: Replace all hyphens with spaces in a certain position in a text file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Why use substring() to check for a single character (it unnecessarily creates a new String)? Why not just use `if (lineOfText.charAt(6) == ' ' )` ?

Comment: Then you have more issues. Like your strange mix of `line` and `lineOfText` and the fact that you print the original `lineOfText` with the whitespace right after the `if`.

Comment: @Tom yes, I didn;t notice that. The OP's code doesn't seem to define a variable named "lineOfText", but just "text". My comment still applies - use `if ( line.charAt(5) == ' ' )`

Comment: Used if ( line.charAt(5) == ' ' ), the new file is identical to the original

Comment: Why 5 when the space is at position 6?

Comment: @FredK My comment wasn't about your comment.

Comment: Yeah, the space is at 6, updated the code. Something interesting just happened in the file, on line 3 (blank space), it got replaced with a  hyphen. On line 4, where there was a hyphen, now has a blank space.

Comment: @Tom Yes, I know - was just trying to clarify my comment to the OP. Also, the OP should note the difference between his comment using `''` and my comment using `' '` (Note the space between the single quotes).

Comment: The updated code has been replaced in the post, with the suggestions above. The hyphen is still not being added when a blank space is met.

Comment: Removed if clause, and now it works. But i really want the if clause, any way to implement? Updated code in post header.

Comment: I know whats the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this , this is gonna be work :

```
String line= inputFile.readLine();

   while(line!= null)
   {
       String outputWithHyphen = line;
       if (line.charAt(6) == ' '){
           outputWithHyphen = line.substring(0,6) + '-' + 
           line.substring(7);
       }
       outputFile.println(outputWithHyphen);
       line= inputFile.readLine();
    }
```

Comment: I don't know what is your main purpose , tell me what you want so that I can help you ...

Comment: what was the output?

Comment: look , you want to write something in your file , lets name it outputWithHyphen , I first initiated it with value of line , I assume that there is no space in the output , then I checked if there is an space in the line , I replaced it with '-' , then I write it in the file

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly from the comments above, you want to replace all spaces you have with a dash - not just in one specific location. You can use the replaceAll function to do this operation instead of looping through character by character:

```
  String myLine = line.replaceAll(" ", "-");
```

Comment: Yes, this works, sorry I should have added that there are many blank spaces that I actually need. Just the blank spaces at this certain index are the ones that I want to remove.